# gRPC "call is closed" exception when calling onNext on server

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Unfortunately, this happens sporadically in production, but I'm unable to reliably reproduce.

gRPC server handing out small but frequent updates to a handful of clients.  Each client makes several requests of the same call with different parameters.  This is perpetually streaming data, there is never an onComplete from the server.

When calling onNext, I get the following error:

```
Feb 20, 2019 10:13:03 AM io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor run
SEVERE: Exception while executing runnable concord.grpc.UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor$SerializingServerCall$$Lambda$47/1901113624@2b4ca8e3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: call is closed
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.sendMessage(ServerCallImpl.java:124)
at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCall.sendMessage(ForwardingServerCall.java:32)
at concord.grpc.UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor$SerializingServerCall.access$1001(UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor.java:142)
at concord.grpc.UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor$SerializingServerCall.lambda$sendMessage$0(UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor.java:158)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.schedule(SerializingExecutor.java:93)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.execute(SerializingExecutor.java:86)
at concord.grpc.UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor$SerializingServerCall.sendMessage(UncaughtExceptionServerInterceptor.java:158)
at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:341)
at myPackage$helper.lambda$calculateChangesAndNotifyObservers$1(myCode.java:229)
```

A list of observers is kept based on gRPC requests to subscribe to the data.  Several clients may request the exact same updates, so each client that comes in is added to the list for the corresponding data.

If they cancel, they are removed from the list via:

```
if( responseObserver instanceof ServerCallStreamObserver<?> )
{
    ((ServerCallStreamObserver<?>) responseObserver).setOnCancelHandler( () ->
    {
        synchronized( _lastSnapshot )
        {
            _observers.remove( responseObserver );
        }                       
    } );
}
```

Is it sane to catch the exception being thrown from onNext and simply remove the client from the list?  Or is there a better method of detection?  Or is there an underlying problem I need to fix?

Comment: The check will only fail if `onComplet()` or `onError()` has been called. Can you verify that neither of these methods are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error too today.
Because I changed the builder value after call build().
error:

```
SyncAepUserResponse.Builder builder = SyncAepUserResponse.newBuilder();
builder.setStatus(Status.newBuilder().setCode(200).setMessage("Successful"))
                    .setMapId(entity.getId()).build();
builder.setCode("200");
responseObserver.onNext(response);
responseObserver.onCompleted();
```

right:

```
SyncAepUserResponse.Builder builder = SyncAepUserResponse.newBuilder();
builder.setCode("200");
builder.setStatus(Status.newBuilder().setCode(200).setMessage("Successful"))
                    .setMapId(entity.getId()).build();
responseObserver.onNext(response);
responseObserver.onCompleted();
```

Comment: I don't have this code base any more, but that seems like a very plausible explanation.  I'll accept it.